# SFTP transfer: how to filter files on name

Tags: apache-camel

I need to transfer a file from SFTP and I try to filter on name with a simple expression language and on the last modified date of the file (=today)

```
fromF("sftp://..." + 
"&filterFile=${file:onlyname} starts with 'someString' && ${date:file:yyyyMMdd} == ${date:now:yyyyMMdd} && ${file:onlyname} ends with '.ext.bak' "
)
```

I got an exception like

> SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: expected symbol functionEnd but was eol at location XX and position is the 's' at the end of "starts"

Please, where did I go wrong in the syntax?

Also, can I filter a file which fileName contains a date like yyyyMMddHHmmss?

Comment: Just [read up](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sftp-component.html) on `fileName` and the example given in the docs

Answer (score 0):

solved by using parameter *include* with a regex and parameter *filterFile* with simple language expression to get file where date modified = current date.